# Buscar valor input de outro arquivo php

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um upload de imagens para uma pasta do servidor, usando o seguinte código:

```
<iframe width="600" name="frmfoto" height="300" frameborder="0" src="teste2.php"></iframe>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function txfoto() {
                    var valor = window.parent.frmfoto.document.getElementById('foto').value;
                    $('#foto').val(valor);
            }

        </script>

        <!-- FOTO 1 -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="fotofundo">* Foto 01</label>  
               <div class="col-md-5">
                   <input id="fotofundo" name="fotofundo" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" onClick="txfoto()" />
               </div>
        </div>
```

No arquivo que realiza o envio, eis o meu input:

```
<input id="foto" name="foto" type="text" class="form-control input-md" value="***************">
```

A foto vai para a pasta do servidor, imprime no input acima, mas não consigo puxar ele para meu outro formulário, quando tento ativar o evento "onClick" no input.

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Posto aqui ou no pastebin?

Comment: Tanto faz, onde vc achar melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `window.parent` não é necessário, pois `window.parent` vai buscar na página acima, como o script esta sendo executado já na pagina acima então ele é irrelevante, basta pegar o `<iframe>`.

Para não conflitar com variáveis globais (no escopo de `window.`) seria mais interessante usar o próprio jQuery, no seletor do jQuery vocÊ pode mudar o contexto, usando [**`.contentWindow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow), desta maneira:

```
 $("<seletor>", <janela>.contentWindow.document);
```

> **Nota:** `<seletor>` e `<janela>` são exemplos e não código

Outro problema é que você na página acima esta usando `fotofundo` e não `foto`, então troque isto:

```
$('#foto').val(valor);
```

Por isto:

```
$('#fotofundo').val(valor);
```

O código todo deve ficar assim:

```
<iframe width="600" name="frmfoto" height="300" frameborder="0" src="teste2.php"></iframe>

<script>
function txfoto() {
     //Pega o iframe
     var frmfoto = $("iframe[name=frmfoto]");

     //Pega o input dentro do iframe
     var input = $("#foto", frmfoto.get(0).contentWindow.document);

     //Passa o valor do input do iframe para o input na janala principal
     $('#fotofundo').val( input.val() );
}
</script>

<!-- FOTO 1 -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="fotofundo">* Foto 01</label>  
       <div class="col-md-5">
           <input id="fotofundo" name="fotofundo" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" onClick="txfoto()" />
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou certinho, obrigado. Só mais uma coisa: Existe algum meio de eu conseguir atualizar o input sem o click? Sabe como é usuário...

Comment: @HebertRichardMassenoDias tente usar `.load` no `<iframe>`

Comment: meu conhecimento é muito pouco em javascript. Poderia me dar uma exemplo ou como devo pesquisar?

Comment: @HebertRichardMassenoDias coloca assim na sua página `$(function () {  $("iframe[name=frmfoto]").on("load", txfoto) });`, não testei ainda, mas creio que deva funcionar. Qualquer coisa cria uma nova pergunta só sobre isto, se não funcionar, que eu irei tentar responder.

Comment: Não funcionou, vou criar outra pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278930/atualizar-input-com-dados-vindo-de-um-iframe-automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Há dois problemas no código:

Um é aqui:

```
window.parent.frmfoto.document.getElementById('foto').value;
```

Para pegar o valor de um elemento no *documento-pai*, deveria usar `window.parent.document`:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('foto').value;
```

O outro é aqui:

```
$('#foto').val(valor);
```

Neste a `id #foto` é inexistente. O correto seria pegar a `id #fotofundo` usando JavaScript puro (isso evita que você carregue o jQuery no frame apenas para fazer isso):

```
document.getElementById('fotofundo').value = valor;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Não tinha visto sua postagem, acabei usando a solução abaixo.